# Where does the custom server settings saved at?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Where does the custom server settings saved at ?

[image]

its not in SLN  nor  PROJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is found in the xml file on the websitecache folder. i found it.